# Prove linearity of impulse response model

Tags: impulse-response, linearity

Given the following time varying model:
$Z(t) = \alpha*t*Z(t-1)$,
how do I go about proving linearity? If you simplify based on some constant at Z(0), you get the general solution $ Z(t) = \alpha^tt!Z(0)$ which is pretty clearly not linear. Am I missunderstanding what is meant by linear?

For transparency this is homework, some I'm happy for general guidance over a full solution.

The question explicitly says "Prove linearity" not "prove or disprove linearity." And the professor has used these homework's for years. So... take that for what it's worth. This is in the context of time series.

Comment: Is "$z$" supposed to be the same as "$Z$"?  What is the full, exact statement of the question?  What is your professor's definition of "linearity"?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit to fix. Great question-- what  could be meant by linearity other than... linearity?

Comment: I can immediately think of many different senses of "linearity" one might reasonably apply here, and I'm sure more will come to mind with further thought.  https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/fod/t describes one relevant sense.  Another is the sense in which this equation is a linear function of $\alpha.$  Another is the sense in which it is a linear function of $(Z_{t-1}, Z_t)$ over the ring of functions of $t.$  Another would be the implicit presence of a linearly additive (or multiplicative) error. Or maybe linearity of the *logarithms* would suffice?

Comment: I am imaging it is in the sense explained in the article you've linked based on superficial similarities between that page and the professors slides, though it appears I should most likely follow up.

Comment: The curious thing is that $\log(Z_t)$ satisfies a linear difference equation in the sense suggested by that reference, but $Z_t$ itself does not.

Comment: Linear with respect to time, or with respect to the lag or some other expression, such as the very convenient modeling choice of $Z(t)/Z(t-1)$ i.e the incremental ratio between time intervals given some initial condition.